# Question about the definition of inverse image of a set

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \to B$ be a function with $T \subseteq B$. Then $f^{-1}(T) = \{x \in A: f(x) \in T\}$ is the definition  of inverse image.

My book says the definition above is equivalent to the rule $x \in f^{-1}(T) \iff f(x) \in T.$ The direction $ x \in f^{-1}(T) \implies f(x) \in T$ is by definition. My question is about the converse of this biconditional. Suppose $A = \{2, 3\}$ and $f(x) = x^2.$ Then $f(-2) \in \{4\}$, but $-2 \not \in A.$ My question is What am I parsing wrong in the definition of preimage? Thanks.

Comment: You and/or the book are forgetting to include the statement "*For every $x\in A$*" before stating the rule.

Comment: To be pedantic $f(-2)$ is undefined as $-2$ is not in the domain of $f$.  So $f(-2)\not \in \{4\}$.

Comment: The book defines image of a set as $f(S) = \{f(x) \in B: x \in S \subseteq A\}$, so the book is in agreement with you on that because then the universal quantification in the def. of preimage is obvious  :) But what if I want to define the domain of $f$ like I've done in OP? What part of the definition of preimage does that violate?

Comment: "What part of the definition of preimage does that violate?"  Then $f$ does *NOT* maps $\{2,3\} \to B$.   $f$ maps $\mathbb R \to B$ so you have to claim $A = \mathbb R$.  Not $A = \{2,3\}$.  $A$ in that definition *is* the domain.  So $f(x)$ where $x \not \in A$ is *not* defined.  Period.

Comment: Part of the definition of every function is the specifying of its domain.  The functions $f:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ via $f(x)=x^2$ is a different function than $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ via $g(x)=x^2$ and $h:\{2,3\}\to \{-7,4,9,16\}$ is yet another.  When you said suppose $f(x) =x^2$ and so $f(-2)\in \{4\}$, I suspect you were defining a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. If I take you entirely on what you say then all I know is $f:A\to B$ and $-2 \in A$.  You can *not* refer to $f(-2)$ *UNLESS* $-2 \in A$ because the definition is for the function $f:A\to B$. *NOT* $f: R\to R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A= \{2,3\}$ and $f:A\to B$ is $f(x) = x^2$ then $f(-2)$ is undefined because $-2\not \in A$.  So $f(-2)\ne 4$ and $f(-2) \not \in \{4\}$.

[To be honest, I  don't quite remember whether $f(-2)$ which in terms of sets is shorthand for $f(\{-2\}) = \emptyset$ or if $f(-2)=f(\{-2\})$ is simply undefined. I suspect the latter.]

If if $x$ is neither $2$ nor $3$ then $f(x) \not \in T$ and so, by the definition, $x \not \in f^{-1}(T)$.  If $x=2$ or $3$ then if $f(x)\in T$ if $x^2 \in T$.  If so then $x\in f^{-1}(T)$.

Might help to do $A= \{-4, -1, 3, 6\}$ and $B=\mathbb N$ and $T= \{$even natural numbers$\}$.

So $f(A) = \{16,1,9,36\}$ and $f^{-1}(T)  = \{-4,6\}$.

Now the definition says if $x \in f^{-1}(T)$ then $f(x)\in T$.  And that is clear true.  If $x$ is $-4$ or $6$ then $x^2$ is an even natural number.

And if $f(x)\in T$ then $x\in f^{-1}(T)$.  And that is also true.  If $f(x) \in T$ then the only values of $A$ that when squared are even natural numbers are $-4, 6$.  So $x \in \{-4,6\} = f^{-1}(T)$.

Comment: In one of the books I found there's this example. Suppose $S = \{2, 3\}$ and $f(x) = x^2$. Then $f(-2) \in f(S)$, but $-2 \not \in S.$ This is to illustrate $f(x) \in f(S)$ doesn't imply $x \in S.$ Why in this case $f(-2)$ is defined?

Comment: Presumably $S \subsetneq $Dom $f$.  So long as $-2 \in $Dom $f$ then $f(-2)$ is defined.  In the definition in the OP, Dom $f = A$.  So, presumably, $-2 \in A$.  (I imagine in the book you cite Dom $f=\mathbb R$ or Dom $f=\mathbb N$.

Comment: The book doesn't explicitly specify the domain of $f$, but it does say $x$ is real. So looks like you're right. Cool!

Comment: So if $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ and $f(x)=x^2$ and $S = \{2,3\}\subset \mathbb Z$ then indeed $f(S) = \{4,9\}$  And $-2\in \mathbb Z$ but $-2\not \in S$.  So $f(-2)$ is defined and $f(-2) = 4\in f(S)$.  But $-2\not \in S$.

Comment: If the book defines $f(x) = x^2$ and claims that "$x$ is real" then he is implying (without explicitely stating) that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$.  A lot of texts will assume, unless otherwise stated, that all functions will have domains of $\mathbb R$.  This is really just avoiding the issue.  Part of the definition (whether explicitely stated or not) of a function is specifying on what domain.